# How to access two models in one repository in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am trying to access two models in one repository and to get the data by joining them. Can someone show an example accessing two models in one repository in Spring Boot?

Comment: Have you made any attempts at this ?

Comment: Firstly you should make some research. If you can not make it by yourself you should share your findings and ask about its possibility.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot directly use two models in one repository if you need x fields from ModelA and y fields from ModelB in your result set.

You have to create a different model ModelC containing only fields you require from ModelA and ModelB. Create a constructor in ModelC with its fields.

In your repository you can call this constructor to get joined data from ModelA and ModelB.

Example:

```
    @Entity
    public class ModelA{
    Integer i;
    String aaa;
    String bbb;
    String ccc;
    //getters and setters
    }


    @Entity
    public class ModelB{
    Integer j;
    String ddd;
    String eee;
    String fff;
    //getters and setters
    }


    @Entity
    public class ModelC{
    String aaa; //from modelA
    String bbbb;
    String ddd;   //from modelB
    public (String a,String b,String d){
    this.aaa=a;
    this.bbb=b;
    this.ddd=d;
    }

    //getters and setters
    }




import yourpackage.ModelC

@Repository
public interface ModelARepository extends JpaRepository<ModelA, Integer> {

@Query("select new ModelC(a.aaa,b.ddd,b.eee) from ModelA a, ModelB b where a.aaa = b.bbb and a.aaa=:x [your query...so on]")
    public List<ModelC> findEntities(@Param("x") String x);
}
```